# Android Studio virtual device display does not match real display (Galaxy Note 2)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, screen-density

I'm developing an app, which is reported to display wrong (have screenshot evidence) on Samsung Galaxy Note II (http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_ii_n7100-4854.php). I've tried to create virtual device with 720x1280 (5.5") display, but it just shows much larger emulated display on my PC (compared to Nexus 5.5 virtual device) and app elements are layed out correctly. Why I cant get same results as on real device? Or how do I do it?

Comment: Use third party emulators like geny motion

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: Geny motion is quite expensive for a learner. Is there a free solution? I dont understand what is wrong with the question, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

The density of your computers screen does not match the density of a current phone. The emulated display size will always be bigger for such high resolution emulators. This should not be a problem as you already found out that the layout is working correctly.

Comment: No, my layout does not work correctly on real device (TextViews are too big and overlap other elements). But I cant reproduce that on virtual device. Despite this Note 2 density is very small (just 280dpi), while Nexus 6P virtual device density is 560dpi and shows small correct virtual display.